# Why is a new object effecting the current one?

Tags: java, eclipse, object

Here I am in the class GameBoard. In this class, I am trying to make a GameTree that returns a list of all possible next moves from this board. While this portion of the code runs, it effects the GameBoard that this code is contained it, resulting in all moves actually being made on the GameBoard, where I am simply trying to return boards with a single move on them. Here is the code within GameBoard:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
    {
        //if valid move, add a board with this move to the list
        if(isValidMove(i, j))
        {
            GameBoard tempBoard = new GameBoard(slots);
            //printout to make sure both object references are different, which they always are
            System.out.println("this board: " + this + " temp: " + tempBoard);
            tempBoard.makeMove(2, i, j);    //use 2 as it is for the AI's move
            tempBoard.rotateA();
            tempBoard.setLastMove(i + " " + j + " " + "A");
            System.out.println("Board with move " + tempBoard.getLastMove());
            tempBoard.printBoard();
            returnList.add(tempBoard);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why this doesn't simply create a new GameBoard object, play the valid move, and add it to the list. Instead by the end of this for loop the GameBoard is filled up with all possible moves.

EDIT: Slots is a private int[][] for the GameBoard class.

Comment: What does `slots` mean?

Comment: I guess it is because all `GameBoard`s share the same reference to `slots` object. Thus a change to one `GamgeBoard` affects all other `GameBoard`s. But please show us what slots is.

Comment: Are `slots` objects that contains where the pieces are? If so, that may be your problem. You are generating a new object that contain the same as the 1st, therefore changes in such object will be seen from both GameBoard objects.

Comment: Yes, you should probably make a copy of the slots when you create a new GameBoard, so you won't move the original slots when trying to compute the next moves.

Comment: Another possibility is that the methods are static and work on a global board.

Comment: Basically, we need to see more code to be certain what's going on. Please try to demonstrate the problem in a short but complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your problem is that the new Gameboard uses *slots* and the old Gameboard also.
So when the new Gameboard is doing something on *slots* it changes them, and because the old Gameboard also uses them its state changes also.

I dont know the structure of *slots* but i assume you should also create a new slots-object for the new Gameboard

Answer (score -1):

You need to break out of the loops as soon as you find the valid move. if this is a stand alone method you can use return; after adding a tempboard to the list.